# Get output of ansible task in proper readable format like JSON

Tags: go, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I am trying to read a content of file. Lets say I have a hosts file in `/etc/hosts`. I want to read the content of the file. When I run ansible playbook it contains several logs containing task name and symbols.

ansible playbook file:

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: "{{ ansible_user }}"
  vars:
    ansible_become_pass: "{{ ansible_ssh_pass }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Read file
      command: cat /etc/hosts
      register: response

    - debug: msg="Content of file is {{ response }}"
```

Logs emitted by ansible:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory.yml playbook.yml 

PLAY [all] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [18.222.139.140]

TASK [Read file] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [18.222.139.140]

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [18.222.139.140] => {
    "msg": "Content of file is {'stderr_lines': [], u'changed': True, u'end': u'2018-10-08 19:21:52.968466', 'failed': False, u'stdout': u'127.0.0.1 localhost\\n\\n# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts\\n::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback\\nfe00::0 ip6-localnet\\nff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix\\nff02::1 ip6-allnodes\\nff02::2 ip6-allrouters\\nff02::3 ip6-allhosts\\nHii just testing', u'cmd': [u'cat', u'/etc/hosts'], u'rc': 0, u'start': u'2018-10-08 19:21:52.966509', u'stderr': u'', u'delta': u'0:00:00.001957', 'stdout_lines': [u'127.0.0.1 localhost', u'', u'# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts', u'::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback', u'fe00::0 ip6-localnet', u'ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix', u'ff02::1 ip6-allnodes', u'ff02::2 ip6-allrouters', u'ff02::3 ip6-allhosts', u'Hii just testing']}"
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
18.222.139.140             : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

The issue is, I just want this output

```
{
  "msg": "Content of file is {'stderr_lines': [], u'changed': True, u'end': u'2018- 
  10-08 19:21:52.968466', 'failed': False, u'stdout': u'127.0.0.1 localhost\\n\\n# 
  The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts\\n::1 ip6-localhost ip6- 
  loopback\\nfe00::0 ip6-localnet\\nff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix\\nff02::1 ip6- 
  allnodes\\nff02::2 ip6-allrouters\\nff02::3 ip6-allhosts\\nHii just testing', 
  u'cmd': [u'cat', u'/etc/hosts'], u'rc': 0, u'start': u'2018-10-08 19:21:52.966509', 
  u'stderr': u'', u'delta': u'0:00:00.001957', 'stdout_lines': [u'127.0.0.1 
  localhost', u'', u'# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts', 
  u'::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback', u'fe00::0 ip6-localnet', u'ff00::0 ip6- 
  mcastprefix', u'ff02::1 ip6-allnodes', u'ff02::2 ip6-allrouters', u'ff02::3 ip6- 
  allhosts', u'Hii just testing']}"
}
```

or any other output that can be parsed through a program.

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

I am using go-lang to invoke `ansible-playbook` command

Comment: I already read that solution and it is not answering my question